# SCP files to a server in LAN from WAN

Tags: scp, ssh-tunnel

I need to SCP a bunch of files from my local machine to a machine in a LAN via a machine with a public ip.

Like this:

my machine -> machine with public IP (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) -> machine with private IP (YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY)

How can I do this as efficient as possible? I could of course SCP the files to the public machine and continue from there, but I'm pretty sure this is doable with tunnels or something?

Thank you!

Comment: what OSes are involved?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to go is port forwarding (because I assume your machine-with-public-IP share its internet connection).
Assuming your public IP maching runs on Windows, you can do that by going to the **Properties** of your shared connection, and in the **Share** tab, clik on **Settings**. Fill in the required values, and you should be good. Of course you have to have a scp server on your machine-with-a-private-IP